# laravel validate conditional image field

Tags: laravel, validation

i have a field that required, and can be 2 value type : String (path) and Image file

how can write validation rule for this ?

if value is string check file_exist and if is file must be image

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found my answer with `FormRequest`

**MyTestFormRequest**

```php
<?php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

class MyTestFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            "image" => ['required']
        ];
        if(is_string($this->image)) {
            $rules['image'][] = new FileExistsRule;
        } else if($this->image instanceof UploadedFile) {
            $rules['image'][] = 'image';
            $rules['image'][] = 'dimensions:ratio=1/1';
        }

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

**FileExistsRule**

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class FileExistsRule implements Rule
{
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return file_exists(public_path($value));
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'The file not exists';
    }
}
```

Comment: Good one. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's an easier way to do this. However, I think a custom rule as such *should* work.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'image' => [
        'required',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if(is_file($value)) {
                if (true !== mb_strpos($value->getMimeType(), "image")) {
                    return $fail($attribute.' is invalid.'); 
                }
            }
            if (is_string($value)) {
                if(! file_exists($value)) {
                    return $fail($attribute.' is invalid.'); 
                }
            }
        },
    ],
]);
```

Comment: thanks, but i have some rules for image files such as dimensions, minWidth and ... i think if i want write rules for each it's incorrect,  i want using laravel validations if image is file